# How can I run a Jimple file?

Tags: java, class, compilation, bytecode, soot

I used soot-2.5.0 and generated a Test.Jimple file. Now I want to run it but I just can't figure out how. I also have a Test.Class file. At first I thought maybe it contains the instructions that I added (the ones that can be seen in the Jimple file) but it doesn't. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

The .class file does contain the instructions in the Jimple file. You must have misinterpreted something. You cannot run Jimple files, you must run the class file.